# Easy proof of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ is uncountable [Big list]

Tags: real-analysis, big-list

I'm looking for a easy proof of  uncountability of $\mathcal P(\mathbb Q)$. I'll contribute with this:

> Let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the power set of  $A$, since $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb Q)$ let be $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb Q)$ such $A\mapsto A$. then $f$ is injective and since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable, then $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb Q)$ is uncountable

Comment: Qué es Q? El conjunto de los números racionales?

Comment: Exactamente @Jccalab, el conjunto de los racionales, por esto puse en los tags análisis real.

Comment: Dear Jccalab and Luis Felipe, we usually stick to English here since the answers and questions are meant not only to benefit to you but to the entire community. Please try to respect that.

Comment: You already have an easy proof right there in the question. How does that not meet what you're looking for?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, sure my friend, he is asking "What is Q? the set of rational numbers"? and I told him: "Yes, is the set of rational numbers, thats why i put in tag real analisys".

Comment: Why downvote? I'm looking for a list of easy proof to add in a presentation for young studens (I'm in 4° year of maths and this is for 1° years students)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva ¡Dios mío!

Comment: hey stop spanish please, he is right, all comments must benefit to the entire community.

Comment: If you want an easy proof, why don't you prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, i.e., in one-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$, Then it becomes trivial that the power sets of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are in one-one correspondence.

Comment: @RobArthan, yes, my idea is show 4-5 proofs of the same theorem and your idea works!

Comment: what is $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: Power set, I'll edit now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ as $f(x) = (-\infty, x) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. It is injective, so $|\mathbb{R}| \leqslant |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})|.$

Comment: it sounds like Dedekind

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

For each real number $x$ pick a strictly increasing sequence $x_n$ of rationals converging to $x$.

Then 
$$f(x)=\{ x_n| n \}$$
is a one to one function from $\mathbb R$ to $P(Q)$. As $\mathbb R$ is uncountable....

Answer (score 2):

Follows directly by [Cantor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

(Note that you asked a proof that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ is uncountable, not that its cardinality is the same of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: nice, Cantor's Theorem is so strong, it's overkill, I like it !

Answer (score 2):

By transfinite induction, I will show that every countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is a set of rationals $S_\alpha\subseteq (0,1)$ which has order type $\alpha$. Then we will have $\omega_1$ clearly distinct sets of rationals.

For $S_0$ we can (indeed, we have to) take an empty set. For set $S_{\alpha+1}$ we can take $\frac{1}{2}S_\alpha\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\}$, where $\frac{1}{2}S_\alpha=\{\frac{1}{2}x:x\in S_\alpha\}$.

Now if $\alpha$ is sum of countably many ordinals $\beta_i$ (some of which could be 0) then we could take $S_\alpha=\frac{1}{2}S_{\beta_1}\cup\frac{1}{4}S_{\beta_2}+\frac{1}{2}\cup\frac{1}{8}S_{\beta_3}+\frac{1}{4}\cup...$ where $aS_\beta+b=\{ax+b:x\in S_\beta\}$.

Comment: Actually this appeals to the axiom of choice. What you can say without the axiom of choice is that you can map $\mathcal P(\Bbb Q)$ *onto* $\omega_1$ so it has to be uncountable.